Can't send push notification to react native expo from firebase
I'm trying to setup push notification for my react native - expo project. So I follow instructions from https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/push-notifications-setup/. All seem ok as I can send notifications to my device using push notificaitons tool from expo https://expo.dev/notifications (with option Force FCM V1).
But here's the problem. When I start testing from firebase, it doesn't seem to send any to my device. I have got FCM registration token (device push token) as instructions from https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/obtaining-a-device-token-for-fcm-or-apns/ and then copy and paste it into firebase but no luck. Seems like it says SENDER_ID_MISMATCH/PERMISSION_DENIED but I have no idea what I have done wrong here.
Could you please help?
Thanks a lot.
I have tried to send push notifications from expo push notificaitons tool and were expecting it to work as well on firebase.
